# Confused in when to use which class in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am learning bootstrap today. I came to the chapter of [bootstrap grid](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp) and I am unable to understand which class out of the 12 classes I should use when. Please guide me. Thank you.

Comment: A container has rows, a row has columns. You must play with different `col-sm col-md` classes to achieve responsive design.

Comment: The classes represent different column widths. You might want to have a look at a bootstrap tutorial (maybe an unofficial one?).

Comment: @Hexaholic sure. Please provide me a url where I can learn from.

Comment: I did not try it myself, but this one looks pretty good and has a lot of examples: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-grid-system.php

Comment: Don't use w3schools; they kinda suck. The official docs are pretty good: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

feel free to read the official documentation about boostrap grid system on http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid